# Adaptec Raid Controller 6405E slower than onboard raid?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid

Running on Windows 8.1 x64. Raid is 0 on two Samsung Evo SSD. Both read and write cache is enabled.

Here's result from onboard raid (ASUS-P9X79-E-WS):

[image]

And here's from the dedicated raid controller Adaptec 6405E:
[image]

Can it really be true, that an onboard raid is faster than a dedicated raid controller?

Comment: You probably don't want your caches enabled.

Comment: Have you updated the Adaptec-Firmware and Driver to the latest versions? If not, do it. We had very big problems with old firmware revisions on Adaptec controllers.

Comment: Hi Lando - yes firmware is latest. This is rather strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 6405E is not fast enough for SSDs. Almost all SSDs have IOP capability that will outrun a 6405E. It's a case of balance - buying fast drives means buying a fast RAID controller. Look at the 71605E for SSD RAID 0,1,10 functionality.
N

Answer (score 1):

I returned the card.

RAID on the motherboard seems way faster.

Comment: Glad you've resolved this issue. Please be sure to mark your answer as accepted when you're able.

Answer (score 1):

RAID 0 is a waste either way. Your SSDs are perfectly capable of providing this speed standalone.

That being said, the Adaptec 6405E controller is connected with a single PCIe Gen2 lane, this results in a theoretical maximum transfer speed of 500 MB/s. This hints at the fact that it is, considering its 4 ports, meant for regular hard disks.

I’d also recommend using a benchmark tool specialized for SSDs.